# Environment to stack a word and a number

Tags: macros, environments, stackengine

There is a requirement to write a list of words, underline each word and place a number centered below the line. Using the `stackengine` package I have prepared the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}    
\usepackage{stackengine,ulem}
\newcommand{\nam}[2]{\stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}}}    

\begin{document}
\nam{First}{5} \nam{Second}{6} \nam{Third}{5} \nam{Fourth}{6} \nam{Fifth}{5} 
\nam{sixth}{5} \nam{Seventh}{7} \nam{Eighth}{6}
\end{document}
```

My question is:

Is there any better way to write the words and number side by side within an environment instead of typing `\nam{word}{Number}` every time.

The interface would look like

```
\begin{numberedEnviron}

hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18 

\end{numberedEnviron}
```

to produce similar result as above. Thanks for the time reading my request and help.

Comment: I am sure that exist an old duplicate/very related question in this site, but I am unable to find it  `:(`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need delimited arguments for such things:

```
\def\nam#1{\nami #1 {} {}}
\def\nami #1 #2 {%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}} \expandafter\nami
  \fi
}
```

Then a call of `\nam{foo 1 bar 2 baz 3}` would alredy do what you need. Hence, there is no need to have an interface that uses an environment. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}    
\usepackage{stackengine,ulem}

\def\numberedwords#1{\numberedwordsaux #1 {} {}}
\def\numberedwordsaux #1 #2 {%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}} \expandafter\numberedwordsaux
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\numberedwords{%
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

Regarding your request to allow blank lines inside the argument of `\numberedwords` you need a `\long` definition that grabs every paragraph and applies the processing via `\stackunder` to them:

```
\long\def\numberedwords#1{\numberedwordsaux#1\par\nil\par}
\def\numberedwordsaux#1\par{%
  \ifx#1\nil\else
    \numberedwordsprocess{#1}\par\vskip 1em plus 4pt minus 4pt
    \expandafter\numberedwordsaux\fi
}
```

Note that `\numberedwordsprocess` now is what `\numberedwords` was in the original solution and that I put some glue inbetween the paragraphs.

[image: output_long]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{stackengine,ulem}

\makeatletter
\long\def\numberedwords#1{%
  \expandafter\numberedwordsaux\trim@pre@space#1\par\nil\par
}
\def\numberedwordsaux#1\par{%
  \ifx#1\nil\else
    \numberedwordsprocess{#1}\par\vskip 1em plus 4pt minus 4pt
    \expandafter\numberedwordsaux\fi
}
\def\numberedwordsprocess#1{\numberedwordsprocessaux #1 {} {}}
\def\numberedwordsprocessaux #1 #2 {%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}}
    \expandafter\numberedwordsprocessaux\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\numberedwords{%
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18

  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18

  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18 
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
  hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
  environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
}
\end{document}
```

---

To use the syntax change that @egreg proposed in his answer in LaTeX2e you can define:

```
\long\def\numberedwords#1{%
  \expandafter\numberedwordsaux\trim@pre@space#1\par\@nil\par}
\def\numberedwordsaux#1\par{%
  \ifx#1\@nil\else
    \numberedwordsprocess{#1}\par\vskip 1em plus 4pt minus 4pt
    \expandafter\numberedwordsaux\fi
}
\def\numberedwordsprocess#1{\numberedwordsprocessaux #1\@nil| }
\def\numberedwordsprocessaux#1|#2 {%
  \ifx#1\@nil\else
    \stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}}
    \expandafter\numberedwordsprocessaux\fi
}
```

and then write `\numberedwords{hello|25 ...}`. As only the input parsing changed all properties of the final original solution are, of course, preserved.

Comment: Thanks for perfect reply and code.  I preferred environment just to handle line breaks.   Two lines cannot be passed as arguments to \numberedwords.  Hence, needed repeated calling of this command.  My text runs over a number of lines, infact a number of couplets.

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety -- You can pass as many lines to `\numberedwords` as you wish (breaking correctly) and therefore you don't need to call it repeatedly (see my update).

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety -- And spacing can easily handled with this solution, e.g. `\def\numberedwords#1{\numberedwordsaux #1 {} {}\par\vspace{1em}\par}`. (Note that I would recommend using a glue for this, not a fixed dimen.)

Comment: thanks for support.  My text runs in many lines.  Not just a big continuous text spread over many lines, but they are several new lines as couplets, stanzas.  I tried with \\ new line character but I could not use this.

Comment: You mean that you have blank lines inside of `numberedEnviron` or `\numberedwords` (resp.)?

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety, see the edit. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Ruben, My text contains a number of lines. ie., in numberedEnviron.  Thanks for the solution this is perfect reply needed thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8):

I'd prefer a different syntax:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{numberedEnviron}
 {
  \par
  \rama_numbered_environ:V \BODY
  \par
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rama_numbered_environ:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_rama_numbered_words_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_rama_numbered_words_seq
   {
    \SplitWord{##1}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \rama_numbered_environ:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SplitWord}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}
 {
  \rama_word_number:nn #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rama_word_number:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand \arraystretch { 0 }
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \strut #1 \\[1pt] \hline \tiny\strut #2
  \end{tabular}
  \c_space_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{numberedEnviron}
hello|25 world|35 this|12 would|39 great|92
environ|21 typesetting|19 exercise|18
hello|25 world|35 this|12 would|39 great|92
environ|21 typesetting|19 exercise|18
hello|25 world|35 this|12 would|39 great|92
environ|21 typesetting|19 exercise|18
hello|25 world|35 this|12 would|39 great|92
environ|21 typesetting|19 exercise|18
\end{numberedEnviron}


\end{document}
```

There's a problem with punctuation, of course.

[image]

Comment: I like your proposal to change the interface. Writing my answer I considered something similar ;)

Comment: @egreg this separator | option is better.  No need to worry about punctuation the text does not have any.  But this code fails when a new line of text is added or \\ newline/linebreak character is given.  Any solution to take two couplets of lines in numberedEnviron.

Comment: I think I remember that `\seq_map_inline:Nn` is faster, but isn't `\seq_map_inline:NN` more idiomatic?

Comment: @SeanAllred Since `\SplitWord` is defined with `xparse` facilities, I prefer the `\seq_map_inline:Nn` version, but `\seq_map_function:NN` would be good too.

Answer (score 7):

Not the full solution, but some kind of automatization:

I'll tried with `expl3` features to split the input `hello 25` etc. for example into items and loop over the items, to provide for `\nam{}{}`. The input has to be converted first with `\Converttolist{}` and later `\DisplayList{}` shows this list according to the `\nam` definition.

The environment `numberedEnvironment` uses this automatically by capturing the environment body within `\BODY` and automatically displaying this.

It's not failsafe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{stackengine,ulem}
\newcommand{\nam}[2]{\stackunder{\uline{#1}}{\tiny{#2}}}

\usepackage{environ}




\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loopcounter}
\setcounter{loopcounter}{1}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\converttolist}{m}{%
  \clist_clear_new:N \l_mylist
  \clist_gset:Nx{\l_mylist}{#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getlistitem}{m}{%
  \clist_item:Nn{\l_mylist}{#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getlistcounter}{m}{%
  \clist_count:N{\l_mylist}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\ConvertToList}{m}{%
  \edef\mystrcpy{}%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{,}[\mystrcpy]%
  \converttolist{\mystrcpy}%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayList}{m}{%
%  Should be replaced later on with a `expl3` loop!
  \forloop[2]{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < #1}{%
    \nam{\getlistitem{\number\value{loopcounter}}}{\getlistitem{\numexpr\value{loopcounter}+1}} 
  }%
}

\NewEnviron{numberedEnviron}{\ConvertToList{\BODY}\DisplayList{\getlistcounter{}}}

\begin{document}


\def\mynumbers{hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18}


\ConvertToList{\mynumbers}
\DisplayList{\getlistcounter{}}


\ConvertToList{This 42 is 45 just 7 another 8 list 1000}
\DisplayList{\getlistcounter{}}

Now with the environment:

\begin{numberedEnviron}
hello 25 world 35 this 12 would 39 great 92
environ 21 typesetting 19 exercise 18
\end{numberedEnviron}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Please bear me, I am a `expl3` newbie ;-)

Here's an output with replicated sequences, all entered to the `numberedEnviron` environment:

[image]